# Update query runs on local server but no on the internet

Tags: php, mysql

Please I need some brain storming. I created an update query as seen below.

```
<?php require_once('Connections/@@@@@.php'); ?>
<?php
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE volunteers, vcodes SET volunteers.sn = vcodes.sn WHERE      volunteers.vid = vcodes.id");
?>
```

It runs behind a form within a web application on my local server and produce the right result but when I upload it to the internet, it does not run but just sits there.

Can any one please help ascertain why it runs only on my local server but not on the internet. I am develop my application within Dreamweaver CS6.

Comment: Does your remote mySQL server is configured to receive remote connections?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: user3614990: But I used mysql_query already as you can see from my detail

Comment: Kermit: Could that be the reason why its not running

Comment: These mysql_* functions are obsolete, but they were not removed yet. So, this is not the reason why the query is not running.

Comment: PLease can some one help me out with a working solution. I have been up all night trying to resolve this issue. I need help please....

Comment: Which mysql server is your script using?

Comment: WAMP in my local PC and Unix online

Comment: "By default, mySql is configured to allow local connections only".  Look at my link below for how to configure your mySql to connect remotely!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) As others have pointed out, mysql_XXX functions are obsolete.  For new code, you should absolutely use the new MySQL APIs: either PDO or mySqli:

- [The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli)

2) Similarly, you should use *prepared statements*.  Not "update..." or "select *".  *Especially* if your server is facing the internet!

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

3) By default, mySql is configured to allow *local* connections only.  This is a Good Thing.  In general, your Web server will face the internet ... but all SQL queries and updates will be local, between your Web Server and MySQL.  This is both more secure and more efficient.

3) If you want to use MySQL remotely, you must do two things:

a) Configure a MySQL account to allow remote access

b) Open your server's firewall to the MySQL port

Here is an article that discusses how to do this:

- http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/mysql-connect-to-your-database-remotely

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason may be your table and fields names are capitalized. You might be using windows in you local where they  are not case sensitive and your remote server might be linux where table and field names are case sensitive. Make sure you are using lowercase letter for your fields and table names.

Comment: I dont think that is the problem. I use lower case in all my tables and fields.